# How to use phonenumber from expo.contacts

Tags: android, react-native, expo, contacts, react-native-flatlist

Im creating a mobile app, where i want to list my contacts and their phonenumbers.
Im using expo contacts and flatlist component where i want to display the contact name and phonenumber.

So, the problem is that i cant figure out how to add the phonenumber to the flatlist component.

```
const [ contact, setContact ] = useState([])

const getContacts = async () => {
    const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync()

    if (status === 'granted') {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
            fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers]
        })
        if (data.length > 0) {
            setContact(data)
            console.log(contact)
        }
    }
}
```

Heres my function to get the contactlist.

Flatlist component:

```
<FlatList 
        keyExtractor={item => item.key} 
        renderItem={({item}) => 
          <View style={styles.listcontainer}>
            <Text style={styles.textProduct}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textAmount}>{item.number}</Text>
          </View>}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={listSeparator} 
        data={contact} 
        
      />
```

the console.log shows that the number is in a separate array, inside the object that is returned from the "getContacts" function.

I cant figure out how to get the number from the array. I've tried using item.phoneNumbers.number with no avail.

Thanks for the responses in ahead. Im happy to provide other info about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`item.phoneNumbers` contains one or multiple numbers. To get the first number every from every item you could use `item.phoneNumbers[0].number`.

Answer (score -1):

```
item?.phoneNumbers && item?.phoneNumbers[0]?.number
```

item?.phoneNumbers: This checks if item exists and has a property called phoneNumbers. If item is null or undefined, the expression will short-circuit, and the subsequent parts won't be evaluated.

item?.phoneNumbers[0]?.number: Assuming item has a phoneNumbers property, this checks if the first element of the phoneNumbers array exists and has a property called number. If the array is empty or doesn't exist, or if the first element is null or undefined, the expression will again short-circuit.

In summary, this code is a defensive way of accessing the number property of the first phone number in the phone numbers array of an item object, making sure to handle cases where item or its properties might be null or undefined. If any part of the chain is not present or is null/undefined, the expression will not throw an error, and the result will be undefined

Comment: Please explain the effect of what you propose and why it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Flagging as very low quality since the answerer hasn't clarified the answer in the last 2 days.